# Programmatically use setTextSize to ?attr/textAppearanceLarge

Tags: android, textview

I'm tinkering with a custom preference right now, and I want to give it a label using TextView. However I can't seem to find a way to specify the text size to "large" using setTextView()

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
TextView title = new TextView(context);
title.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.attr.textAppearanceLarge);
```

or try

```
setTextAppearance(context, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
```

use the above code and try

Comment: This isn't working, the correct response is `setTextAppearance(context, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);`

Comment: problem with that is that you don't know for a fact that android.R.attr.textAppearanceLarge points at android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large

Comment: If you used app_compat theme the use "R.style.TextAppearance_AppCompat_Large"

Answer (score 1):

As the syntax has changed since starting API Level 23 (Marshmallow) also a few users mentioned that `android.R.attr.textAppearanceLarge` did not work for them as it did not work for me. Here is the updated version...

```
Button b = new Button(getContext());

if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M )
    b.setTextAppearance( android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium );
else
    b.setTextAppearance( getContext(), android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium );
```